# How to redirect from a JSON response?

Tags: javascript, python, json, redirect, flask

So I am trying to use Flask and a Javascript uploader(Dropzone) to upload files and redirect after the upload is complete. Files are getting uploaded fine, but using the traditional redirect in flask:

```
return (redirect ("http://somesite.com"))
```

Does nothing, page does not change. I think this is because of this: The request headers of the files being sent are set to `Accept:"application/json"`, and the response headers are being sent in `<"text/html; charset=utf-8"` How can I return a json response and then redirect from it? Just doing

```
 return (redirect (jsonify("http://somesite.com")))
```

gives an error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I know browsers won't redirect from Json headers anyway. How can I send the url to redirect to  from Flask back to my JS app clientside and redirect from there? 
I already tested this with a normal HTML form to submit the files and it worked perfectly so I'm pretty sure it is the JSON issue. Thank you.

Comment: How does the browser send the request? It doesn't matter what the mimetype *is* for a 302 redirect (it is the HTTP status that counts), but if you are trying to redirect an AJAX request you need to update the JavaScript code to do the browser page change instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the mimetype for the response:

```
response = redirect('http://somesite.com')
response.mimetype = 'application/json'

return response
```

Or:

```
return make_response(redirect('http://example.com'), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: The mimetype has nothing to do with it; the OP is most likely using AJAX here.

Comment: @jack: I will cherish it borother.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AJAX calls, then you need to return the destination location in the JSON response and then set the value of window.location.href to this in your JS code.