# Redirect to external url while sending a JSON object or String from flask app

Tags: python, redirect, post, cookies, flask

I have a flask application where I need to redirect to an URL outside flask root path (www.externalurl.com). This URL, on the client side, requires consuming some information (either a JSON object or a String). How to send this information along while redirecting?

Consider below example,

```
from flask import Flask,redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<some_path>')
def some_method():
    # some_info = {'key1' : 'value1'}
    response = redirect("http://www.externalurl.com", code=302)
    return response
```

I have come across setting headers & cookies. But, I came to know that the cookie size should be less than 4k and I don't want this limitation. Are there any standard ways of doing this?

Comment: It depends what `externalurl.com` expects from your side. GET arguments? or what?

Comment: What are you doing with the information at the external url? Are you entering it in text fields etc?

Comment: That's something i can control. But, i can not have the data as GET arguments as the url length is limitted and i might want to send JSON object as well. I can not set cookies as the max size of all the cookies is limitted to 4k. If there is any way to send this info, i can adjust what externalurl.com expects.

Comment: @Harrison This needs to be stored in JavaScript's localStroage which I keep referring to for various operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect from a JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268823/how-to-redirect-from-a-json-response)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have control over `externalurl.com`

You can associate some key or hash with the JSON object and store them to be retrieved by a script on `externalurl.com` later.

So, store it in a database at `example.com` and setup an endpoint for it to be requested later.

```
@app.route('/<some_path>')
def some_method():
    some_info = {'key1' : 'value1'}
    db_entry = JsonInfo(some_info)
    db.add(db_entry)
    db.commit()
    hash = db_entry.hash
    response = redirect("http://www.externalurl.com?hash={}".format(hash), code=302)
    return response

@app.route('/get-json')
def get_json():
    hash = request.args.get("hash")
    json_info = JsonInfo.query.filter_by(hash=hash).first()
    return jsonify(json_info)
```

Then on the side of `externalurl.com` parse the hash from the get request, then use that to make a request to `https://example.com/get-json?hash=abc123` to retreive the info.